# Trying to add a HeaderView to ListView in android But I cant add

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, header, oncreate

In my activity, I had a ListView. 
In that I am trying to add header view to list view looks not working to me.
When i add header view using `addHeaderView()` method it throws

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called
```

When I comment out `listView.addHeaderView(header);`, it works fine.
But i called `addHeaderview()` method before `setAdapter()` method. I cant figure out why this error occured. Let me know what error in my code.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    TextView header= new TextView(this);
    header.setText("Header");
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        list.add("Row "+i);
    }
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list));
```

Comment: i think you are doing setAdapter somewhere in the code before setting a header, please post the whole class, if possible

Comment: this is my full code in onCreate() method @BhavikMehta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it guys. I had added `android:entries` attribute in xml file. So that `setAdapter()` called before `addHeaderView()` method.

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/confess_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:entries="@array/sample_array"
            android:padding="@dimen/medium"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/medium"
            android:background="#fbf8f8"
            android:scrollbars="none">

        </ListView>
```

When I removed `android:entries` attribute from xml, Its working fine. Thanks @Bhavik Mehta.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
TextView header= new TextView(this);
header.setText("Header");
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    list.add("Row "+i);
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanx @Ravi Dev , I found where i mistaked. answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like this :

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_id);

    //code to add header and footer to listview
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, listView,
            false);
    ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, listView,
            false);
    listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    listView.addFooterView(footer, null, false);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: Thanx @Nikhil Verma , I found where i mistaked. answer posted.